# Exception in creating a delete query in EntityManager

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql, entitymanager

Here is the method:

```
public void deleteVotesByReplyID(long replyId) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
           int re = em.createQuery("delete object(o) 
                                    from Vote as o 
                                    where o.memberReply.id = '"+replyId+"'"
                                  ).executeUpdate();       
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

What's wrong in above query? (used jpa 1.0)

Comment: What does the exception stack trace say? Which JPA implementation do you use?

Comment: nothing..only java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occured while creating a query in EntityManager. JPA 1.0

Comment: Which implementation? Hibernate, EclipseLink, other?

Comment: Toplink......................

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps due to the fact that a delete query starts

```
DELETE FROM entity_name [[AS] identification_variable] [WHERE <filter>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query could have been written as

```
"DELETE from Vote o where o.memberReply.id = 'someId'"
```

Also DELETE queries can only be executed within an active transaction. You will want

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
query.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

and also to

```
catch (Exception e) {em.getTransaction().rollback();}
```